# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'close'

Tags: asp-classic

I have a section of code in one of my scripts that is getting an error in its syntax.

```
if(status <> true and Request.QueryString("selectId") = "undefined") then
strConn ="PROVIDER=foobar;Server=foo;Database=foo;Uid=bar;Pwd=bar;"
Set cnt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
rs1.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cnt.ConnectionString= strConn
cnt.Open strConn

sql="Select * from rule1 where skucode='" & Request.Form("txthidden") & "' and letter1id  ='" & Request.Form("lrt1") & "' and letter2id ='" & Request.Form("Select1") & "' and letter3id ='" & Request.Form("Select2") & "'"
rs1.Open  sql,cnt,2,2
if not rs1.EOF then
Response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Rules already exists!');</script>")
else

  sql="INSERT INTO rule1 (letter1id,letter2id,letter3id,HTML,skucode) VALUES "
  sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("lrt1") & "',"
  sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("Select1") & "',"
  sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("Select2") & "',"
  sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("txthtml") & "',"
  sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("txthidden") & "')"  
cnt.Execute sql
 Response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Rules Added successfully!');window.location='" & "viewrule1.asp?skucodes=" & Request.Form("txthidden") &   "';</script>")
end if
rs1.Close
cnt.close
```

The error message I get is:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'close'.

/path/file.asp, line 75
```

Comment: There is an `End If` missing after `cnt.close()`.

Comment: @j.w.r this would have caused a compilation error (Syntax Error) however the actual error message is runtime error.

Comment: What is line 75? Also, try changing `rs1.Open  sql,cnt,2,2` to `Set rs1=cnt.Execute(sql)` it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing it, you can detach it completely:

```
set cnt = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem. All i think is if your data is too long or not. Sometimes it occurs when your row limit exceeds. SQL Server 6.5 allows a maximum row size of 1962 bytes and SQL Server 7.0 allows a maximum row size of 8060 bytes. Its just an assumption

Answer (score 0):

Presuming it's the last line that's throwing the error, I'd replace it with:

```
If IsObject(cnt) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If cnt.State = 1 Then ' 1 = adStateOpen '
        cnt.Close
    End If
    Set cnt = Nothing
    Err.Clear
    On Error Goto 0
End If
```

`cnt` is probably already closed by the time it reaches that portion of your script which is why it's throwing the error. Checking its status before closing it needs to be wrapped in `On Error Resume Next` logic, otherwise it'll throw another error.